# Can't remove retired, physically removed drive from Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have a RAID 5 [Storage Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ECQ.png) built in Windows 10. I used Hard Disk Sentinel to monitor the health of my drives but one of them went from 100% health to inoperable in an instant. It was causing file operations (move, copy, open) to hang the entire system and I would need a forced restart to get back up and running.

In safe mode, I pulled the drive and swapped in a drive of the same model. Then let it work on optimizing for ~50 hours. Now I cannot remove the dead drive, it just gives me the
["Can't remove drive"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNsK.png) error.

My files seem intact, though I have so many that I have no way of knowing if everything remains uncorrupted.

Comment: Conflict between "pulled the drive" and "cannot remove the dead drive". Please explain.

Comment: It is physically removed. Unplugged, unclipped, unscrewed, etc.

Storage Spaces, the software, claims it cannot remove the drive from a virtual storage space RAID.

Comment: Have you followed the steps for how to [Replace failed disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn782852(v=ws.11))? Have you missed out on a step?